# Tick marks don't scale in graphics -- why, and how to fix this?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

As we rasterize 3D images at higher and higher resolution, every image element should get proportionally bigger and bigger.  However, tick marks stop growing after a while.  Is there a way to ensure that tick marks should grown proportionally to the rest of the graphic, like text does?

---

Illustration:

```
g = Graphics3D[Sphere[], Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 200]

Table[Image[
  ImageResize[Rasterize[g, "Image", ImageResolution -> n 72], 
   Scaled[1/n]], Magnification -> 1], {n, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Column[Table[
   Image[Rasterize[g, "Image", ImageResolution -> n 72], Magnification -> 1], 
   {n, 6}], Alignment -> Left]
```

**[Click here to see the output (too big to be conveniently inlined)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHBb5.png)**

Comment: This is possibly a bug. I know there are issues with 2D plots and ticks not scaling in rasterized images.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. You should have a look at http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/ (if you haven't already). The main package includes a package for custom ticking.

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 Indeed, the ticks package is available separately here as well: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599

Comment: If this is your actual example and not a toy one then it would seem that a tick function for this graphic is pretty straight forward as per the answer below. I don't use styling in tick function however, I prefer to set that separately with `TickStyle`. AFAIK manual ticks looks like the only way to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html "More information" and "Application" sections. You can specify tick length like this:

[image: Tick mark size]
[image: Plot 3D with custom tick marks]

Comment: Indeed, it is an interesting finding that manually specified ticks do seem to scale.  I don't want to manually specify tick positions though, as this is completely unnecessary and also a lot of work (if I want to make it look nice).  The defaults are fine.  How can I make the defaults scale correctly?  Note that auto-generated tick specifications are not easily retrieved: `Options[g, Ticks]` gives `Automatic`.